# Differentiating a Distribution

Tags: distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

If a function $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then if $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have that
\begin{align*}
\partial_j(\mathrm{test }\ f)(\phi) = -\mathrm{test}\ f(\partial_j\phi) = \mathrm{test}\ \partial_jf(\phi).
\end{align*}
This is easy to prove using partial integration. My question instead concerns differentiating functions which fail to be continuous at some points, say $f(x,y) = \log(x^2+y^2)$ and

**I wonder what properties could be placed on the function (distribution) $f$ to ensure that**

\begin{align*}
\partial_j(\mathrm{test }\ f)(\phi) = \mathrm{test}\ \partial_jf(\phi).
\end{align*}
**where differentiation $\partial_jf$ is the almost everywhere derivative**.
Clearly it is not enough to assume for instance that $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})$ since the Heaviside function $\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}$ is a contradiction to this having derivative equal to delta. Considering the case $n=1$ I figured that if $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ the condition that $f,f'\in L^1_{loc}$ and

$$f(\epsilon)\phi(\epsilon)-f(-\epsilon)\phi(-\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$$
then implies that $\frac{d}{dx}\mathrm{test}\ f(\phi) = \mathrm{test}\ \frac{d}{dx}f(\phi)$ 
holds. Indeed then

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\mathrm{test}\ f(\phi) & = -\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\frac{d}{dx}\phi(x)dx = \lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0}-\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}f(x)\frac{d}{dx}\phi(x)dx\\
& = \lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0}\left(-f(\epsilon)\phi(\epsilon)+f(-\epsilon)\phi(-\epsilon)+\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\phi(x)dx \right)\\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\phi(x)dx = \mathrm{test}\ \frac{d}{dx}f(\phi)
\end{align*}
However for greater dimensions this condition becomes too complicated. Is there some simple condition which could be placed on $f$ to ensure the above in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what is $pv(1/x)$ the distributional derivative of $\log |x|$. It is not the same as $1/x$. Both are the same when acting on test functions vanishing at $0$ because $\log |x|$ is $L^1_{loc}$ at $0$ and continuous elsewhere.

Comment: No I am aware of that so I wonder what conditions can be placed to guarantee that

Comment: To guarantee what ? That if $D^a f$ is $L^1_{loc}$ away from $0$ what condition on $\phi$ implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{x \not \in U_n} D^a f(x) \phi(x)dx =\int D^a f(x) \phi(x)dx$ for any $U_n \supset U_{n+1} , \bigcap U_n = \{0\}$ ? An obvious sufficient condition is that the distribution $ D^a f \ \phi $ is $L^1_{loc}$ at $0$. With $f = \log |x|, f' = pv(1/x)$ then $f' \phi$ is $L^1_{loc}$ when $\phi(0 ) =0$. With $ f(x) = 1_{x > 0},f' = \delta$ then $f' \phi$ is $L^1_{loc}$ when $\phi(0 ) =0$.